# Struggling to design addresses table for fast querying

Tags: performance, optimization, normalization, address, query-performance

I have two tables: addresses and locations.

```
Locations
zipcode
city
county
state

Addresses
line1
line2
city
county
state
zipcode  

Posts
Id
Address_id
Body
```

All my users are required to provide at least a personal address and some need to provide the business address.

My users can create two types of posts: first requires to have a full address and the second requires just the location (state, city, zipcode).

Now, the issue comes because I need to allow searches for posts based on location. The search is always based on city state and zipcode (not street numbers).

Does it make sense to place all the addresses inside the Addresses table and for the posts that need just the state, city and zipcode to leave the other fields blank? Would this slow down posts searches based on addresses?

Would having in my DB 5.000-10.000 users and maybe 200.000 addresses really slow down the process of searching for first type of posts based on the address?

Comment: How are you linking post to address?  You need to perform data design as a whole.   Start with what you think is a clean data design (e.g. 3NF) and then only deviate if you have performance issues.  At only 200,000 you are not even close to pushing the limits of a database.

Comment: Edited question to reflect relation between address and post. Its just a simple one to many (more likely one to one)

Comment: Uh, still does not show how you are linking.  So Posts has an addressID.

Comment: Yes. Posts have an address_id while users themselves use many to many with type field in the pivot table.

Comment: Having two separate address tables will be far more complicated and confusing than would ever be worth the potential tiny bit of performance gain. And that potential is really only going to be realized when you have 10x the data you are talking about. Empty string fields take up 0 bytes.

Comment: Uh, you still have not show how those tables are linked.   Many to many - how?  Type field in pivot table - where is that table?

Comment: If you were going to normalize this at all, it would make most sense to add `LocationID` to the Addresses table and remove the common fields from Addresses. City, state, zip is a rather finite set and hence will be repeated often in the Addresses table.

Answer (score 1):

A single address table will be a clean and efficient solution to maintain and execute queries against. From the information you've given the main reason you might not want this is you have two well defined use cases, one of which expects additional fields to be completed while the other accepts a significant number of blank fields.

Handle this in your application logic - users should never be allowed to progress or commit data if all required fields are not validated in the front end.

If you do not already have a design that makes the address/user type clear (e.g. FK to user with a user type) you could always add a bit flag to your address table that defines the address type. If you store both a personal and a business address you may need this anyway.

```
AddressIsPersonal BIT NOT NULL
```

This will allow you to ensure a unique PK and to query Address table directly for data checks and searches. For example if `AddressIsPersonal = FALSE` means we expect to see complete addresses returned and we may only be searching for business posts.